# How to find table tag td values using jQuery filter selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Calories </td>
        <td>TargetValue1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Protein</td>
        <td>TargetValue2</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td>Protein</td>
        <td>TargetValue3</td>
    </tr>
```

How can I select all **second td** values?

I tried

```
    $.each($("#nutritab tbody tr td:eq(1)"),function(i , item){
        alert($(item).text());  
    });
```

but that only returns the first values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use `nth-child` selector instead of `:eq(index)`

*The `:nth-child(n)` selector matches **every element** that is the `nth child()`(`Index starts from 1`)*

*The `:eq(index)` selector selects the **element** at index n within the matched set.(`Zero-based index`)*

```js
$.each($("#nutritab tr td:nth-child(2)"), function(i, item) {
  alert($(item).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='nutritab'>
  <tr>
    <td>Calories</td>
    <td>TargetValue1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Protein</td>
    <td>TargetValue2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Protein</td>
    <td>TargetValue3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ... I'm failed .... Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: nth-chiled

Comment: that selector can't use  in jquery-1.11.1.min.js?

Comment: I have also updated `jQuery version`.. It can not be because of version!

Comment: yes it it work!! successfully  it was my mistake!! i'm really appreciate !!

Comment: I'm glad it helped! _Happy Coding_

Answer (score 1):

```js
$.each($("#nutritab tbody tr"), function(i, item) {
  alert($(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='nutritab'>
  <tr>
    <td>Calories</td>
    <td>TargetValue1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Protein</td>
    <td>TargetValue2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Protein</td>
    <td>TargetValue3</td>
  </tr>
```

1. First name the id to the table
2. Use .`nth-child()` *note:starts at 1*

Comment: thank you very much !! have a nice day!  I solved my problem!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:nth-child(n)` selector, it matches every element that is the `nth child() of selector`:

```js
$('.tb').each(function(index, tr) {
 alert($(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tb">
  <tr>
        <td>Calories </td>
        <td>TargetValue1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Protein</td>
        <td>TargetValue2</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td>Protein</td>
        <td>TargetValue3</td>
    </tr> 
</table>
```